# I'm not getting any styling on Area 51

Tags: support, area-51

I'm not getting any styling on Area 51, on any browser, on any OS.

[image: No Styling on Area 51, Screenshot, IE and Chrome, Windows 7]

I'm on Virgin Media in the UK. I know they had [an issue a while ago with StackOverflow being blocked](http://community.virginmedia.com/t5/Up-to-120Mb-Setup-Equipment/stackoverflow-com/td-p/1722156).

Could this be something similar? Or is this a known issue with Area 51 at the moment?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The styles on Area51 are not loaded through HTTPS, so when you connect to the site using HTTPS, your browser will refuse to load the unsafely loaded files. Use normal HTTP protocol instead.

Comment: Bonus reading [here](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/)

Comment: @rene nice article, though a bit outdated

Comment: @3ventic content gets stale after 6 months?

Comment: @rene I said *a bit* outdated, not useless ;)